# Certain shortcut key-sequences don't trigger shortcuts when pressed in PyQT5

Tags: python, pyqt

Here is some code that reproduces my 'error' so to speak:

```
import sys


from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import  QKeySequence
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QShortcut, QTextEdit, QApplication)


app = QApplication([])
wid = QTextEdit()

wid.show()
short = QShortcut(QKeySequence(Qt.Key_F2), wid)
short.activated.connect(sys.exit)
app.exec()
```

Hitting F2 , as expected, shuts the program down. If I were to use other keys as an argument, such as `QKeySequence(Qt.Key_Control)` or `QKeySequence(Qt.Key_Control + Qt.Key_F2)`, nothing happens when I hit said keys upon launching the program

I can't seem to figure out what about them prevents them from triggering the shortcut. From the reading on other SO threads I've gone through about shortcuts, some state that the widget in question might not be focused. I've made sure my widgets were focused , but despite that, the shortcuts don't trigger when I use such keys

Some state that a widget's child's keyPressEvent might eat up the shortcut. This confuses me. I did go through the docs, and shortcutEvents happen to be their own unique individual event. I don't understand why a widget's keyPressEvent handler might choose to handle a shortcutEvent passed to it

I believe it has something to do with the keys I specified for the shortcuts themselves, but I can't quite put my finger on it. Sure, just using F2 as the shortcut IS an option, but I'd really like to allow for the pressing of say, Shift + F2 or Control + F2 as a shortcut, which isn't working for some odd reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing part of the key sequence to `Qt.CTRL` worked for me; so perhaps something wrong with `Qt.Key_Control`in the sequence.`Qt.SHIFT` doesnt seem to work for `QTextEdit` or `QLineEdit` but does with other widgets. Perhaps use a `QWidget` as a container and use the keysequence on that rather than `QTextEdit` widget alone. Otherwise; subclass `QTextEdit` and overwrite `keyPressEvent`

```
import sys


from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import  QKeySequence
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QShortcut, QWidget, QGridLayout, QTextEdit, QApplication)


app = QApplication([])

wid = QWidget()
layout=QGridLayout(wid)
tEdit=QTextEdit()
layout.addWidget(tEdit)
wid.show()
short = QShortcut(QKeySequence(Qt.SHIFT+Qt.Key_P), wid)
#short = QShortcut(QKeySequence(Qt.CTRL+Qt.Key_F2), wid)
#short = QShortcut(QKeySequence(Qt.SHIFT+Qt.Key_1), wid) - doesnt work on textedit/lineedit but works on other widgets
short.activated.connect(sys.exit)
wid.setFocus() #simulate focus on widget
app.exec()
```

Comment: Oddly, having a key sequence consisting of JUST Qt.CTRL doesn't seem to work, nor do other key sequences like Qt.Key_1 work. Why would that be so? Also, I am curious, why wouldn't Key_Control work? Do they not correspond to the same key?

Comment: As far as I can see; the Key_# works for me with Qt.CTRL, perhaps Qt.Key_Control is OS specific? Generally shift/ctrl keys need something else apart of sequence

Comment: I see, I've got CTRL + 1 working now. Why doesn't JUST 1 as a shortcut work? Something like `QKeySequence(Qt.Key_1)`?

Comment: Read updated answer; perhaps wrap your QTextEdit in a QWidget/QMainWindow container and use keysequences on that.

Comment: After reading your updated answer, would it be right to assume that a shortcut consisting of SHIFT + 1 would not work as long as a textedit/lineedit is focused?

Comment: I provided an example of using a container widget; otherwise overwrite keyPressEvent in QTextEdit. And correct; you can code it up and check it out; it works with SHIFT when QWidget is in focus. Please mark answer as solved; if I answered your question.

Comment: @Hash well, QTextEdit *is* a widget that accepts text input, "shift+1" is a printable character, creating and accepting a shortcut for that is not very smart.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, shortcuts can be created with strings:

```
short = QShortcut(QKeySequence('ctrl+f2'), wid)
```

That said, I believe you don't understand what keyboard modifiers are and how UI interaction works.

In the comments you asked: "a key sequence consisting of JUST `Qt.CTRL` doesn't seem to work".

The <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> are [*modifier keys*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modifier_key), which in UI environments are not keys that can trigger anything on their own. They *modify* the behavior of the other keys.

Most importantly, all those keys are ***very*** important in a widget that accepts user input (especially text), and it doesn't make a lot of sense to trigger an action with a key that might be necessary for the *basic* widget purpose (what if the user just wants to make a clipboard operation and you trigger the quit with Ctrl?).

Then you also ask "Why doesn't JUST 1 as a shortcut work?".
Same concept as above: "1" is a type-able character, why would you prevent writing <kbd>1</kbd> and quit the program with that?

Keyboard shortcuts should almost always be based on keyboard combinations of modifiers and letter keys, with the only exception of function keys and special keys that can be triggered safely without involving text input.

<sup>Note: don't use `sys.exit` in Qt signals or related functions unless you know what you're doing. Use `QApplication.quit`.</sup>

Comment: Why would Qt.CTRL work but not Qt.Control in situations where Qt.CTRL works? That's always puzzled me. Also, in regards to the usage of Qapplication.quit, how would I use it in a window that I intend to import into another file which contains the application? Passing the Qapplication to that would be a little confusing. Is there  better way to handle it in such situations?

Comment: @Hash If by `Qt.Control` you mean `Qt.Key_Control`, that depends on *what* you're checking. `Qt.CTRL` (or `Qt.ControlModifier`) is a modifier key, `Qt.Key_Control` is the physical key. If you need to construct a shortcut, you must use the modifier, if you're checking keyboard events and want to know when the Ctrl key has been pressed/released, you need `Key_Control`. [`quit()`](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#quit) is a static function, you don't need the instance (which you can get anyway using the static `QApplication.instance()`), since there should always be *one* QApplication.

Comment: Even if it is a static function, if a Qapplication isn't defined in the global scope of the window being imported, how would it be defined? Would a good approach be to simply import Qapplication in the window to be imported, or should I pass Qapplication as an arg to the window constructor?

Comment: @Hash Obviously, QApplication must be imported from PyQt5.QtWidgets.